# android lollipop with moto g (2nd gen)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, downgrade

I have updated my Moto G (2nd Gen) to the new version of Android (5.0.2), after which I am facing hang and slowness issues.

How can I revert this back to my old version of Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just added the `downgrade` tag to your question. While waiting for answers showing up, please check out [other questions using that tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downgrade?sort=frequent), your answer might already be there.

Comment: Yes you can. But you have do it all yourself. Get the factory image of Kitkat for your device & flash it. You can find detailed step by step guide on the internet on various sites.

Comment: I also encountered with the same problem. But still don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies as it's been a while since this question was asked but thought I'd answer it it since I had a similar experience now.

I also have a Motorola G2 and it was having slowness issue just last week, and I saw on android pit website they suggest you go in to the developer options and speed up the animation which can cause slowness if it's set to default that is 1 second, I changed it to .5 seconds and it really makes a big difference, and now everything works much faster.

And there's another suggestion there as well for clearing the cache. I'm posting a link here: https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-speed-up-the-moto-g-2014-for-better-performance